# How to search multiple keywords in all subreddits in Reddit using PRAW in Python

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am trying to search a list of multiple key words in Reddit posts in all subreddits. At the moment my dataframe is showing just results for the last word in the keyword_list list which is 'maritime history'. Does anyone know how I can get this to search all of the words?

```
# Creating keyword list
keyword_list = ['maritime heritage', 'shipwreck', 'shipwrecks', 'coastal archeaology', 'maritime archaeology', 
                'maritime ecologies', 'marine archeaology', 'marine heritage', 'cultural marine heritage', 'marine culutral haritage', 'maritime history']

# Searching in all subreddits  
all = reddit.subreddit("all")
df = pd.DataFrame() # creating dataframe for displaying scraped data

# creating lists for storing scraped data
titles=[]
scores=[]
ids=[]

# looping over posts and scraping it
for submission in all.search(keyword_list, limit=None):
    titles.append(submission.title)
    scores.append(submission.score) #upvotes
    ids.append(submission.id)


df['Title'] = titles
df['Id'] = ids
df['Upvotes'] = scores #upvotes

print(df.shape)
df.head(10)
```

Comment: Can you share what you are trying to mimic? For instance, is it this? https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=%27maritime%20heritage%27%2C%20%27shipwreck%27%2C%20%27shipwrecks%27%2C%20%27coastal%20archeaology%27%2C%20%27maritime%20archaeology%27%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27maritime%20ecologies%27%2C%20%27marine%20archeaology%27%2C%20%27marine%20heritage%27%2C%20%27cultural%20marine%20heritage%27%2C%20%27marine%20culutral%20haritage%27%2C%20%27maritime%20history%27

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what I'm trying to get! And then to have all of those titles in data frame. Currently I'm just getting a data frame with titles that include the last keyword in the list - I'm not sure how to get all of them at once?

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked or not by selecting it as the answer or leaving a comment with the error or issue that you faced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straightforward change. You’re wanting to search for multiple things, but you’re not wanting to make multiple searches (queries).

Your keywords should be something like:

```
# Creating keyword list
keyword_list = '"maritime heritage", "shipwreck", "shipwrecks", "coastal archaeology", "maritime archaeology", "maritime ecologies", "marine archaeology", "marine heritage", "cultural marine heritage", "marine cultural heritage", "maritime history"'
```

And that will pass your single query, containing multiple keywords, and return the posts you want to process.

As long as your current post-processing is working correctly for the ‘maritime history’ responses then you shouldn’t have any issue processing the responses to the new query.

Comment: Thank you for this! It's now using all the words to search but it is not keeping them within phrases. So I am getting the words 'marine' and 'maritime' coming up separately to 'heritage' or 'archaeology' in some posts. Is there a way to make sure they only appear together? 

I also only have 231 posts even though I have put limit as none - any ideas on this? Thank you!

Comment: @HannahCocks I am not actually familiar with the library, I could just tell what you were doing before wasn't going to work because Python. Let me take a look at the phrases bit, but the 231 I have no insight on.

Comment: @HannahCocks Try my edited list - let me know if it helps and/or does what you are expecting/wanting.

Comment: thanks for sending that through! Unfortunately it just found random posts when I tried this list? So I have no idea what happened there! I've just resorted to doing a separate chunk of code for each word at this point.